# How to find out the location of mvn folder?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I want to create a Maven Project through command prompt. I have installed Eclipse+Maven.How to find out the location of mvn folder?

Comment: What do you mean by `mvn folder` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Maven that is included in Eclipse cannot be used on the command line.

You need to install a separate command line Maven for that.

Comment: Why it can't be used? Can you please explain?

Comment: The Maven of Eclipse is integrated in Ecilpse. There is no folder with `mvn` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best if you provide more details of exactly what you want or need to do.  When you say you want to create a maven project through the command prompt, do you mean with a maven archetype?  I have a feeling you don't know what that is.

If you want to create a new Maven project, you can do it in Eclipse, with "File"->"New"->"Other..."->(filter for Maven)->"MavenProject".